# Rails - options for the all_startups() method in the Angellist API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Does anyone know what all of the options are for the all_startups() method of the Client class of the Angellist API?  I have been looking online for about an hour now, and I can't find anything.

Here is the link to the Github repo:

https://github.com/paulsingh/angellist-api/blob/master/lib/angellist_api/client/startups.rb

The method is on line 54.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all of the options:

```
:trending, :featured, :new, :hiring, :raising
```

Comment: pagination only works while using 'raising'. is there any way to do it with other options?

Answer (score 2):

Yea, it is definitely not very easy to find a list of all_startups() methods. Here are a few that I know of:

```
:raising, :featured, :trending
```

I found them from:

:raising -> [AngelList API](https://angel.co/api/spec/startups)

:featured -> https://angel.co/startups?filter=featured (check out the url)

- same for :trending, found from the URL on their site